# OIDC - SAML2 integration

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, saml-2.0

I need to integrate the oauth2 OIDC flow wit SAML flow.
So I need to haver a client that starts an authentication code flow wiht spring authorization server.
Spring authorization server should perform a SAML flow with the IDP.
A the end of the process the client should receive a JWT access token.
Is this possible using spring authorization server?
Please help
Thank you

Comment: Yes, this should be possible. You need to properly configure SAS to start an authentication (with whatever IDP necessary) whenever an authorize request comes in unauthenticated. After the successful login, your SAS instance should then continue with the autorization code flow. The definitive configuration depends on more details that you need to provide about the setup.

Comment: is there any code snippet I can be inspired from? The flow is more or less clear but I'm lacking the real implementation based on spring authorization server